# How to add legend to scatter plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, scatter-plot

I have assigned a shape and color to each point, and I want to draw the legend according to the group data, but I can't add the legend..

```
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

name <- c("S1","S1","S1","S2","S2","S3","S3","S3","S4","S4","S5")
x <- c(1,5,9,8,5,6,7,4,3,6,4)
y <- c(3,8,9,5,7,5,3,8,9,3,4)
Shape <- c(21,21,21,22,22,23,23,23,24,24,25)
Color <- c("red","red","red","blue","blue","green","green","green","purple","purple","black")

df <- data.frame(x,y,name,Shape,Color)

graph1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill = Color, shape = Shape))+
  geom_point(size = 4)+
  scale_shape_identity()+
  scale_fill_identity()
graph1
```

the x and y is the main data. The name is the group. The Shape and Color is the shape and color I assigned for all those point. How to draw a legend according to the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x ,y = y, fill = name, shape = name)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = unique(df$Color)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = unique(df$Shape))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly the way I want to plot the data! Thank you for your answer! I tried every way to justify it (I'm totally roockie in this).

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `aes` parameter `color` :-)

```r
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

name <- c('S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2', 'S3', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S5')
x <- c(1, 5, 9, 8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 6, 4)
y <- c(3, 8, 9, 5, 7, 5, 3, 8, 9, 3, 4)
Shape <- c(21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25)
Color <- c('red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'purple', 'purple', 'black')

df <- data.frame(x, y, name, Shape, Color)

graph1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = Color, color = name, shape = Shape)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_fill_identity()
graph1
```

You will note that using the group (`name`) as the basis for the legend makes this plot confusing, but in any case, you can add the `color` param to ensure that your legend is rendered.

[image: plot image]

if you use `Color` as the value for the `color` parameter you get the following:

[image: better param for legend]

Comment: Thank you. But I tried to add the color to aes and the final image's legend didn't show the dot's shape and color correctly (all the dot in the legend is filled circle and their color is different from the color I assigned)

Comment: If you want the in the legend to match the color you assigned: `graph1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = Color, color = Color, shape = Shape)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_fill_identity()`

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I hope that the dot in my final image are exactly the way I assigned them, including the shape and filled color. The color in aes seems to change the edge color of my dot but I hope them to stay black. I'll also try to use other ways to justify the legend to make sure that the dots' shape and color is exactly the same in the plot.